# How does Jensen Shannon divergence and KL divergence correlate?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, it.information-theory

I am wondering if there is way to derive the correlation between Jensen Shannon divergence and KL divergence for two distributions: *P* and *Q*, in order to show that if *JSD(P,Q)* decreases, *KLD(P,Q)* decreases as well.

*JSD(P,Q) = 0.5*KLD(P,(P+Q)/2) + 0.5*KLD(Q,(P+Q)/2)*